# Windows8 live tile text truncated

Tags: text, tiles

I am new to windows8 app dev and trying to create a live tile and every thing worked fine but text on tile is getting truncated for some reason. I did not find any place to change default characters limit. Please guide me on this

```
public sealed class TileUpdater : IBackgroundTask
    {
        public void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
        {
            var defferal = taskInstance.GetDeferral();

            var updater = TileUpdateManager.CreateTileUpdaterForApplication();
            updater.EnableNotificationQueue(true);

            updater.Clear();

            List<Updates> updatesList = GetUpdatesList();

            for (int i = 0; i < updatesList.Count; i++)
            {
                var tile = TileUpdateManager.GetTemplateContent(TileTemplateType.TileWideText02);
                tile.GetElementsByTagName("text")[0].InnerText = updatesList[i].Title;
                tile.GetElementsByTagName("text")[1].InnerText = updatesList[i].Description;
                updater.Update(new TileNotification(tile));
            }
            defferal.Complete();
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it finally. I updated template type from 
 var tile = TileUpdateManager.GetTemplateContent(TileTemplateType.TileWideText02

to 
 var tile = TileUpdateManager.GetTemplateContent(TileTemplateType.TileWideText09

and it worked finally.